# Progressbar not being displayed on one line

Tags: python, progress-bar

I'm trying to create a progress bar and I've tried this code

```
from progressbar import *


widgets = ['Test: ', Percentage(), ' ', Bar(marker='0',left='[',right=']'),
           ' ', ETA(), ' ', FileTransferSpeed()] #see docs for other options

pbar = ProgressBar(widgets=widgets, maxval=500)
pbar.start()

for i in range(100,500+1,50):
    # here do something long at each iteration
    pbar.update(i) #this adds a little symbol at each iteration
pbar.finish()
print
```

but basically it creates something like this:

[image: Progression bar]

Is there a way to have the progress bar directly on one line? starting from 0 until the end?

Comment: When asking question about third-party modules (those that are not part of Python's standard library), it's important to indicate exactly which one you are using.

Comment: Your result may also depend on how you are running your code. If it it;s in an IDE like VS-Studio Code, PyCharm, IDLE, etc, say so in the question.

Comment: uhm well I'm simply looking for a progression bar which shows the progression only on one line as I wrote. I'm not so expert in python and in third-part modules. Thanks for support

Comment: I explained what a third-party module is (one the doesn't come with Python), and not only have you not added any of the useful information I suggested to your question, you have accepted a "code-only" answer with no explanation containing code the won't run. It's mystifying…

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
import sys
import time
import threading

def barra():
    global stop
    global kill
    print ('Waiting reboot NV....  '),
    sys.stdout.flush()
    i = 0
    while stop != True:
        if (i%4) == 0:
            sys.stdout.write('.')
        elif (i%4) == 1:
            sys.stdout.write('.')
        elif (i%4) == 2:
            sys.stdout.write('.')
        elif (i%4) == 3:
            sys.stdout.write('.')

        sys.stdout.flush()
        time.sleep(5)
        i+=1

    if kill == True:
        print ('....ABORT!'),
    else:
        print ('....done!'),


kill = False
stop = False
p = barra()
p.start()

try:
    #anything you want to run.
    time.sleep(300)
    stop = True
except KeyboardInterrupt or EOFError:
    kill = True
    stop = True
```

Comment: This code in incorrect. `barra` is simply a function, not a thread and therefore has no `start()` method. The `threading` module isn't even being used.